# PG::UndefinedTable error when running RSpec test suite in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an RSpec test suite that tests many things including the creation of a model called `CompanyReportByReturnOnCapital`. The associated table used to be called `company_report_by_return_on_capitals`, due to Rails' automatic pluralization, and I've since run a migration to rename the table to `company_reports_by_return_on_capital`.

However when I run `rake` to run the test suite, I receive the following error:

```
1) StockReader#create_company_reports_by_roc creates reports
 Failure/Error: CompanyReportByReturnOnCapital.delete_all
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "company_report_by_return_on_capitals" does not exist
   LINE 1: DELETE FROM "company_report_by_return_on_capitals"
                       ^
   : DELETE FROM "company_report_by_return_on_capitals"
 # ./spec/lib/stock_reader_spec.rb:102:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My schema.rb:

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141029193309) do

      # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
      enable_extension "plpgsql"

      create_table "company_reports_by_earnings_yield", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "symbol"
        t.string   "market_cap"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.string   "ebit"
        t.string   "ebit_date"
        t.string   "enterprise_value"
        t.string   "earnings_yield"
        t.string   "fixed_assets"
        t.string   "working_capital"
        t.string   "return_on_capital"
        t.string   "market_cap_date"
        t.string   "total_assets"
        t.string   "total_assets_date"
        t.string   "current_assets"
        t.string   "current_assets_date"
        t.string   "total_debt"
        t.string   "total_debt_date"
        t.string   "cash_and_equivalents"
        t.string   "cash_and_equivalents_date"
        t.string   "working_capital_date"
      end

      create_table "company_reports_by_return_on_capital", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "symbol"
        t.string   "ebit"
        t.string   "ebit_date"
        t.string   "market_cap"
        t.string   "market_cap_date"
        t.string   "working_capital"
        t.string   "working_capital_date"
        t.string   "total_assets"
        t.string   "total_assets_date"
        t.string   "current_assets"
        t.string   "current_assets_date"
        t.string   "total_debt"
        t.string   "total_debt_date"
        t.string   "cash_and_equivalents"
        t.string   "cash_and_equivalents_date"
        t.string   "fixed_assets"
        t.string   "enterprise_value"
        t.string   "earnings_yield"
        t.string   "return_on_capital"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

  end
```

My migration files renaming the table:

```
class CreateCompanyReportByReturnOnCapitals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :company_report_by_return_on_capitals do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :symbol
      t.string :ebit
      t.string :ebit_date
      t.string :market_cap
      t.string :market_cap_date
      t.string :working_capital
      t.string :working_capital_date
      t.string :total_assets
      t.string :total_assets_date
      t.string :current_assets
      t.string :current_assets_date
      t.string :total_debt
      t.string :total_debt_date
      t.string :cash_and_equivalents
      t.string :cash_and_equivalents_date
      t.string :fixed_assets
      t.string :enterprise_value
      t.string :earnings_yield
      t.string :return_on_capital

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class RenameCompanyReportByReturnOnCapitals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :company_report_by_return_on_capitals, :company_report_by_return_on_capital
  end
end
```

```
class RenameReturnOnCapitalReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :company_report_by_return_on_capital, :company_reports_by_return_on_capital
  end
end
```

Here is the test in spec/lib/stock_reader_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'stock_reader'

RSpec.describe StockReader do

  describe '#create_company_reports_by_roc' do
    before(:each) do
      CompanyReportByReturnOnCapital.delete_all
    end
    it 'creates reports' do
      StockReader.create_company_reports_by_roc($return_on_capital_array)
      expect(CompanyReportByReturnOnCapital.count).to eq(2)
    end
  end
end
```

And finally, lib/stock_reader.rb where the actual code resides:

```
require 'csv'
require 'httparty'

module StockReader
  def self.create_company_reports_by_roc(company_data_array)
    company_data_array.each do |company|
      CompanyReportByReturnOnCapital.create(
       symbol: company[:symbol], 
       enterprise_value: company[:enterprise_value].to_s,          
       enterprise_value_date: company[:enterprise_value_date],
       ebit: company[:ebit].to_s,
       ebit_date: company[:ebit_date],
       earnings_yield: company[:earnings_yield].to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

So far I've tried resetting the test database using the following commands:

`RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`, `rake db:test:load`, `rake db:test:prepare`

AND the development database using:
`bin/rake db:drop` and `bin/rake db:create` and `bin/rake db:migrate` with no success.

I'm out of ideas!

Just for good measure I'll include my model, app/models/company_report_by_return_on_capital.rb:

```
class CompanyReportByReturnOnCapital < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had to add inflections to my config/initializers/inflections.rb file so that Rails would not expect a table called `company_report_by_return_on_capitals`. Despite many `db:drop`'s and migrations, Rails was still expecting this although `company_report_by_return_on_capitals` was nowhere to be found in my application. All's well now.

Answer (score 3):

Something similar happened for me where PG was looking for a non-existent table which gave me errors when I tried to test.
I deleted the fixture file corresponding to the non-existent table and that solved the issue for me.